# TFS 2017 notifications not working

Tags: tfs

I am using tfs 2017. In the alert settings I have configured gmail smtp and when I try send test mail it works, mails are sent to the email address. I have configured notifications and set the delivery settings for the same. But the emails are not getting sent when ever I make any changes in any work item.
Could any one help out to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for on-premises TFS, you [**must configure an SMTP sever**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/setup-customize-alerts) in order for team members to see the Notifications option from their account menu and to receive notifications. Double this setting and make sure your SMTP server worked

According to your screenshot you are trying to [manage notifications for a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/manage-team-notifications):

> **Deliver to**      Specific team members
>   **Roles**     Assigned To(New)  Assigned
>   To(Previous ), Previous Assignee, Current Assignee

Make sure your account is applied to those roles for the changed work item.

And in this case,
by default, email notifications will be sent to **your preferred email address**: `xxx@xxx.com`. You could check and update your address in your user profile, check if the E-Mail address is the one you would like to use.

Besides, also try to change the Deliver to Team email address and directly input your E-Mail Address. Then test again.

[image]

Comment: After removing the filter criteria it worked. I am able to receive emails from tfs.

Comment: @RajashreePethkar authorized as means the user who changed the work item. <> means not include. So, if yourself change the work item, you will not get the notifications. For details you could take a look at [What does "Authorized as" field works for when creating an alert?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d0da52f-a6ac-497f-b3f1-b5d14e946cca/what-does-authorized-as-field-works-for-when-creating-an-alert?forum=tfsadmin)